# Unwanted propType errors on external methods arguments

Tags: javascript, eslint, gatsby, react-proptypes

**Framework:** Gatsby

**Context:**

I've created a `FormDropdown wrapper component` which imports a 3rd party react component. Where I had to overwrite properties and methods.

**Problem:**

For code readability, instead of writing the methods directly in the component properties I have built custom functions outside. This external function generate ESLINT props errors on the arguments pass to this functions, but this doesn't happen if I write the function directly on the property.
See code example alternatives below:

**Code:**

```
const FormDropdown = () => {

    const customDropdownRenderer = (props, state, methods) => {
        //logic
    }

    return (
        <Box sx={styles.dropdownWrapper}>
            <Select
                dropdownRenderer={(props, state, methods) =>
                    //ESLINT errors
                    customDropdownRenderer(props, state, methods)
                }
                itemRenderer={(props, state, methods) => {
                   //logic (no ESLINT errors)
                }}
            />
        </Box>
    );
};
```

**Yarn lint proptype errors/warnings:**

```
'state' is missing in props validation
'state.search' is missing in props validation
'state.values' is missing in props validation
```

To avoid this errors, I tried defining them in proptypes, it fix the lint error but I still get other errors on the devtools console:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `state` is marked as required in `FormDropdown`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

**Questions:**

- Why calling an external method creates this errors and if I write the function directly it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

As you don't using and type checking like `Flow` or `Typescript` it's your only line of defense against runtime-types-bugs.

> Declaring all these method vars in proptypes is correct?

Yes. But a better solution is to re-write this component as passing so many props is unreadable and unmaintainable.

Read about [Composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/design-principles.html#composition).

> If not, is there a way to avoid it?

It is advised but you can avoid it by turning off the lint rule for a specific file:

```
/* eslint react/prop-types: 0 */
```

Or in `.eslintrc` for the project:

```
{
 "plugins": [
     "react"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": 0
  }
}
```

> Google `eslintrc disable "react/prop-types"` for more solutions.

Comment: Disabling proptypes is not an option. 
I've edited my question, tried to make it more specific and simple.

Comment: Its very unclear whats going on, you dont show any proprypes

Comment: I'm just importing an 3rd party component and overwriting properties and methods. Imagine my wrapper component doesn't have any props. If I create a custom method for the imported component, like I show in the example, ESLINT throughs props errors for the arguments in that custom method which is wrong and weird because they are not props they are arguments. But if I write the function directly, no errors appear.

Comment: I cant imagine, try making a producible example